# API giving data in second render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I was trying to fetch API with react.js but on first render its gives nothing and the second render its gives data. This makes it so when I try to access the data later for an image I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'news.article' of undefined, because it is initially empty.

How can I solve this?

[image: photo]

Here is my code ..

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const HomeContent = () => {
    const [news, updateNews] = useState([]);
    console.log(news);
    useEffect(() => {
        const api = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=940c56bd75da495592edd812cce82149'
        fetch(api)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => updateNews(data))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }, [])

    return (
        <>

        </>
    );
};

export default HomeContent;
```

Comment: You don't need to "solve" it. That's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: This makes it so when I try to access the data later for an image I get an error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'news.articles' of undefined, because it is initially empty.

Comment: Re edit: At no point in the code you've shared with us do you try to read any property of `news` (let alone `news.articles` so that code can't produce that error. (And if `news` is going to get a property called `articles` then it doesn't make sense to initialize it to an empty *array*).

Comment: Usually you would have an additional `loading` state, that you set to `false` when the request finished. You can then render some kind of loading indicator, while `loading` is still `true`. For a more sophisticated app you will also need some state to handle errors while fetching the data.

Comment: Can I have an example of code? @trixn

Comment: You initialize `news` as an empty array but your response is not an array. Also `news.status` will be `undefined` until your request finished successfully.

Comment: @Jay There are plenty of online resources that deal with exactly that as it is maybe one of the most common things to deal with in a real world app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with the code itself, the output you receive is expected. However, you can render the content after it is retrieved as such

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const HomeContent = () => {
    const [news, updateNews] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);    

    console.log(news);
    useEffect(() => {
        const api = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=940c56bd75da495592edd812cce82149'
        fetch(api)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => { 
                updateNews(data.articles);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
               setIsLoading(false);
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading ? 
                <p>Loading...</p> :
                // Some JSX rendering the data
            }
        </>
    );
};

export default HomeContent;
```